# TYPO3 extbase access sorting

Tags: sorting, typo3, extbase

when using the fluid debug array I see a nested array lige this:

```
building
 [+]floor
    [+]room
```

When clicking the + the sub array is expanded sorted by UID and not by the "sorting" as I have specified in my repository.

```
protected $defaultOrderings = array(
    'sorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
);
```

Can I either access the sorting value somehow?
Or can I somehow force TYPO3 to sort its own array after sorting?

Comment: can you sort manually in the BE?

Comment: You need to provide more information if you want help. I guess building->floor->room is not a nested array but are some models connected with relations. What kind of relations? 1:n, m:n? What is possible depends on the kind of relation.

Comment: Indeed, we need more information. This is probably misconfigured in your `TCA`.

Answer (score 1):

The sorting field should not be manually set.

If you want to sort the entries please use the DataHandler like the Typo3 Backend.

Here is a solution:
[TYPO3 CommandController: How to set table field "sorting" of Extbase Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896377/typo3-commandcontroller-how-to-set-table-field-sorting-of-extbase-object/41016860#41016860)

Answer (score 0):

By "clicking the +", you mean that the subobjects aren't sorted the way you specified in the TCA?

The sorting is lost on the subobjects because Extbases PersistenceRepository by default only sorts by the order specified in the object itself. But thats no biggie, you just have to specify to order by the subproperty, either with the defaultOrderings property or when building the query:

```
class FloorRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {

    // Order by BE sorting
    protected $defaultOrderings = array(
        'sorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
        'room.sorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
    );

    ...

 }
```

This should give you the Rooms of a Floor, Ordered by the sorting of the Floors, and in each Floor, the Rooms sorted by their sorting.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the sorting property by defining it as integer in your model and creating the related getter (setter if needed)

protected $sorting